# Quickly populating a DataGrid from an SQL Server CE database?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server CE database and from there I need to populate a datagrid, it's all running on Windows Mobile which is obviously very slow.

My current method which might not be the best is I create a list out of a class which is used as a datasource and I populate that list and set the data grid to have its data source as the list.

This is phenomenally slow since I'm doing `SqlCeReader.read()` operations for each row.

Is there a way to do this faster or am I pretty much screwed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SqlCEResultSet - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb219485(v=sql.90)